# Could there be a problem with using a product as an interface for a slideshow?

Tags: product, cache, image

My client has a slideshow on their homepage and to make it easy for them to update it, I was thinking of making a slideshow 'product' where they upload the images and enter their corresponding urls as the image labels.

I thought this would be good because the product interface is familiar to them and magento would be aware of the images to cache.

Is there any reason this might be a bad idea other than them mistakenly deleting the product?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any negative impact it may have. Just loading an product at the home page and looping through it's images will not do any harm.

You may also consider some ready-made slider-like extensions available for Magento. Some of them even have an interface for managing slides contents.

But after all your idea is quite creative :-)

Comment: Cool, thanks. It worked great and they loved it